# Accessing Odoo on my NAS with docker and portainer from external internet

Tags: docker, localhost, odoo, nas

I have installed Odoo on my NAS with `Docker` and `Portainer`.

I can access the Odoo with localhost in my office, eg, `http://0.0.0.0:port`.
I would like to know how to access with external internet, for example in my home?

Any ideas?

Comment: If your router support port forwarding, then you could forard port 80 in your router into your internal service or to a proxy like nginxproxymanager to route the requests into your internal service. Othwerwise you could use cloudflare Tunnel  and route external traffic based on domains to your internal service.